# Wordpress post_content gets deleted in cron after wp_update_post

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, post-content, wp-kses

I'm developing a Wordpress plugin (integrated with **WooCommerce**) that fetches HTML Content from an API, and add it to a WP Post as post_content into an iframe, this way:

```
kses_remove_filters();
$newData['description'] = str_replace("\n", "", $newData['description']);
$newData['description'] = str_replace("\t", "", $newData['description']);
$post = $this->getPostByAPIId($product->api_id);

$id = $post->ID ?? get_post($product->woo_id)->ID;
if (isset($id) && !empty($id)) {
    $this->wpdb->update(
        "{$this->wpdb->prefix}posts",
        [
            'post_content'  => '<iframe class="custom-post" id="custom_product_post_content" src="' . htmlspecialchars('data:text/html,' . stripslashes(rawurlencode($newData['description']))) . '" style="display: block;width:100vw; height:100vh; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999; min-height:300px!important;"></iframe>'
        ],
        [
            'ID' => $id
        ]
    );
}
kses_init_filters();
```

Even if I put the **kses_remove_filters()**, when I open wordpress to check the new content, I find out that the *post_content* is empty.

If I try to debug the plugin with xdebug, I find out that post_content is updated, but when I refresh wordpress, the post_content disappear.

A few project specifications before starting:

1. I can't just embed the API as src
2. I don't want to fetch content via javascript
3. I used an **iframe** because I know that wordpress post_content can't embed a full HTML page like this: `html > head { title } > body { style and various tags }`
4. I don't write the HTML personally, I need to embed it via the API

Feel free to ask any question. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Even if I use `wp_update_post(['ID' => $id, 'post_content' => '...'])` the post_content doesn't get updated and I get empty content.

**Edit 2**:

I enabled query log on my development environment and during debug session I found out that the function that "remove" the post_content is

```
wc_update_product_stock( $postId, $quantity )
```

Even if I wrap this function with a `kses_remove_filters()`, the function doesn't change its behaviour. Is there any way to "change" this behaviour without changing stock quantity update?

Comment: Why are you inserting directly into the database and not using `wp_update_post()`?

Comment: Because `wp_update_post()` doesn't update the post_content

Comment: What? Of course it does.

Comment: I tried to perform `wp_update_post(['ID' => $id, 'post_content' => '...'])` but when I refresh the wordpress page, or I select the post_content from the posts table, I get empty post_content.

Comment: Aren't you having the same problem with the version in your question?

Comment: When does this code? Do you have any proof that it's running? How do you known the problem is with `wp_update_post()`, and not that the code just isn't running?

Comment: I used xdebug to debug my code, even with `wp_update_post()` the post_content gets updated. But when I go to the wordpress post, the content is empty, and it's empty in DB too. I have a clean wordpress installation with Wordpress, Woocommerce and my plugin.

Comment: When does this code run? What is the hook?

Comment: It's a wp-cron scheduled with `wp_schedule_event( time(), 'my_custom_recurrence', 'my_posts_update')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86279/discussion-between-kalizi-and-jacob-peattie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WooCommerce stock quantity update by using

```
wc_update_product_stock( $postId, $quantity )
```

used to remove post_content, so I put quantity update before the post_content update.